# How to do bidirectional synchronization between Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created two Elasticsearch clusters in different regions, both running version 8.x. These clusters need to be synchronized so that if Region A becomes unavailable, Region B can handle the data, and once Region A is back online, the data should be synchronized.

Tried cross cluster replication and below is the sample config executed on Cluster A Node 1:

```
xpack.ccr.auto_follow_pattern: "*"
xpack.ccr.auto_follow_enabled: true
xpack.ccr.auto_follow_patterns:
  - name: "all-indices"
    remote_cluster: "cluster-b"
    leader_index_patterns:
      - "*"
    follow_index_pattern: "{{leader_index}}-follower"
    max_outstanding_read_requests: 2
```